# Upload image to server efficiently in Android

Tags: java, android, post, bitmap, httpurlconnection

I have an app that needs to send an image to a server. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
//We have a variable "image" that is the Bitmap that we want to send
File imagesFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
File file = null;
try {
    if(imagesFolder.exists() || imagesFolder.mkdirs()) {
        file = new File(imagesFolder, "input.jpg");
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        //checkWifiOnAndConnected returns true if wifi is on and false if mobile data is being used
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, checkWifiOnAndConnected() ? 90 : 80, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d("Error", "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
}
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
URL url = new URL(serverUrl);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(40000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(40000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(entity.getContentLength());
conn.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
entity.writeTo(os);
os.close();
conn.connect();
if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
    Log.e("UPLOAD", "HTTP 200 OK.");
```

It works, but it's kinda slow, specially when using mobile data (obviously). And I would like to know if there's a more efficient and faster way to send this image.

Comment: Q: How large are the files?  Q: What's the typical bandwidth/transfer speed from the handset?  Q: Have you verified that most/all of the "slowness" is occurring during the network transfer?  I'm guessing the best you can do is play with the "quality" parameter in your JPEG compression (sacrifice "quality" in favor of "smaller size")

Comment: You can try gzipping the upload - other than that data transfer takes time, if the image is large, it is expected to take 1+ seconds.

Comment: I would not first compress a bitmap to file and then send the file. Try to compress the bitmap directly to the output stream of the connection.